Can a simple DC motor detect physical resistance or manual movement?
I'm currently fixing the tray mechanism of a CD player. I have replaced the broken cogwheel and the drive belt, but one problem persists: sometimes when I press the "open" button, the tray will start to open and then immediately close again. There is a mechanism by which you can close the tray by giving it a small push manually, and I suspect this mechanism is being triggered too easily. I have tried to identify this mechanism, but I can't find anything mechanical that does this, so I'm left wondering:
Can a simple DC motor be used to detect physical resistance or manual movement? I assume that you could detect whether the power draw goes over a certain mA value, and then deduce that the movement is being obstructed. But how would you detect the push when the motor isn't working? Does an electrical motor act like a dynamo when turned manually, allowing you to detect when it is being turned?

Former CD/DVD player designer here.
In a word, no. The tray motor isn't used for sensing.
Tray control is much, much simpler than that. The tray has a set of limit switches for 'tray fully open' and 'tray fully closed'. Those and the motor drive are all that is used to manage the tray. The rest is done by controller firmware.
If you manually push the tray, firmware detects 'tray fully open' switch changing state, so it knows you did that. The controller helpfully continues on by starting the tray motor to finish a tray close movement.
The switches also can detect a blockage. Tray is commanded 'open', the controller starts the tray moving, and also starts a timer. If something blocks the tray, the timer times out and firmware sees that the 'tray fully open' switch wasn't hit in time, so the controller reverses the motor to re-close the tray.
It could be that the 'tray fully open' limit switch is faulty. It could also be possible that the 'open' (actually open/close) button is corroded sending two events.
Now, can a motor be monitored for physical resistance? Sure. If the motor experiences an overcurrent, this could be sensed by its driver and reported to the controller. But this would add extra expense, so I've not seen it used.

Thanks. From how little the tray opens before it closes again, I'm guessing a double-triggering open/close button might be the culprit.
